# How to add a UITableView in UIScrollView with PageControl

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

In my ViewController, i have two uitableview. One of them is static with one section and two rows, and the other has so one section but four rows.
I would like to do an `UIScrollview` with `UIPageControl`, and in each page, i would like to add the second tableView with four rows. But number of page in scrollView can be change. So i try with UILabel and it works but with tableView i can't see it.

I don't know if you understand my problem. I put the code of my loop.

```
for (int i = 1; i < [listAllContactDetails count] + 1; i++) 
 {
        UILabel *nomContact = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i-1)*320, 20, 320, 30)];
        nomContact.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        nomContact.text = [[listAllContactDetails objectAtIndex:i-1] valueForKey:@"name"];
        [scroller addSubview:nomContact];
        [nomContact release];
 }

 scroller.delegate = self;
 scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*[listAllContactDetails count], 249);
 scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;

 pageControl.numberOfPages = [listAllContactDetails count];
 pageControl.currentPage = 0;
```

This code right with UILabel but not with UITableView.

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to add a UITableView to each page by setting its frame in a loop just the same as you are doing with the labels.

The problem is hooking up the data source. You'll need to bind each table view's datasource property to your view controller inside your loop. Then give each table in the loop a different .tag property based on the loop index. In your datasource methods you'll need to check the tag of the tableview to work out which page it is. Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [listAllContactDetails count]; i++) 
 {
        UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*320, 0, 320, 200) style:...]
        tableView.dataSource = self;
        tableView.tag = i + 1;
        [scroller addSubview:tableView];
        [tableView release];
 }

 scroller.delegate = self;
 scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*[listAllContactDetails count], 249);
 scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;

 pageControl.numberOfPages = [listAllContactDetails count];
 pageControl.currentPage = 0;
```

...

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
        NSInteger tag = tableView.tag;
        switch (tag)
        {
            case 1:
                return numberOfRowsForPage1;
            case 2:
                return numberOfRowsForPage2;
            etc...
        }
 }
```

Comment: it will be good but i don't understand because about numberofRowinSections works, but about heightforrowatindexpath doesn't work. They are no change when i changed the return.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but there is a small problem in here: The tableview are being created and populated but you can't scrolldown in the tableview. Any solutions to it?